# Config caching css/js files at Nginx

Tags: file, caching, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using nginx host by Ubuntu 14.04

My config file :

```
  server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name testing.com;



location /site/admin/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/site/admin/src/;
}

location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
     expires 1y;
     access_log off;
     add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

I've got some errors

```
[error] 29224#0: *10047 open()     "/usr/share/nginx/html/site/admin/assets/js/jquery.nestable.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Actually that file is located :

```
 /usr/share/nginx/html/site/admin/src/assets/js/jquery.nestable.js
```

**How can i set my config file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `location ~ \.(css|js)$` block inherits `root /usr/share/nginx/html` from the server block.

Also, regular expression location blocks take precedence over prefix location blocks - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

You can force your `location /site/admin/` block to override regular expression location blocks at the same level by using the `^~` modifier:

```
location ^~ /site/admin/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/site/admin/src/;
}
```

The above location block is a prefix location (and not a regular expression location block). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Of course, this also means that URIs beginning with `/site/admin/` and ending with `.css` or `.js` will no longer have their caching parameters changed. This can be fixed by adding a nested location block, as follows:

```
location ^~ /site/admin/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/site/admin/src/;

    location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
```